# Simple proof involving $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This seems easy, but now I fell like it's not right.  I don't think you can go back along the same line of reasoning when proving an "iff" statement (or can you?)...

> Show that $|x-a|<\varepsilon$ if and only if $a-\varepsilon<x<a+\varepsilon$.

Left to right:

for $\varepsilon>0$, we have $-\varepsilon<x-a<\varepsilon \Rightarrow a-\varepsilon<x<a+\varepsilon$

Right to left:

$a-\varepsilon<x<a+\varepsilon \Rightarrow -\varepsilon<x-a<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |x-a|<\varepsilon.$

Is that an okay proof?

Comment: when you went from $-\epsilon < x - a < \epsilon$  to  $a - \epsilon < x < a + \epsilon$ you added $a$ to both sides of the inequality. Similarly, you can start with  $a - \epsilon < x < a + \epsilon$ and subtract $a$ from both sides. This is true because $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field.

Comment: So in essence it is not the same operations, therefore we can essentially "undo" what we did from left to right?

Comment: Think about this:Let $a$, $b$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that if $a < b$ then $a + c < b + c$? If so, it doesn't matter whether $a, b$ or $c$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks!  I get it now.  I should just trust the logic and not think because it's too easy it must be wrong

Comment: Re: "[going] back along the same line of reasoning", sometimes you can, sometimes you can't.  In this case it seems to work fine.  The only thing I would suggest is that even if the argument is essentially the same in both directions, in order to make the logic clear you should actually write it out in both directions.  This is exactly what you have done and it looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$ We consider three cases $x<a$, $a<x$ or $a=x$. The last case is trivial. Now If $x<a$, then $|x-a|=-(x-a)<\varepsilon$, i.e., $x>a-\varepsilon$. Now since $x<a$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then $x<a+\varepsilon$. Thus $a-\varepsilon<x<a+\varepsilon$, as desired. The case when $a<x$ is similar just with the roles of $a$ and $x$ interchanged.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Now suppose  $a-\varepsilon<x<a+\varepsilon$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $x-a< 0$. Then $|x-a|=-(x-a)=a-x<\varepsilon$, i.e., $|x-a|< \varepsilon$.